# Zend Framework 2 in IIS in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, iis-7, zend-framework2, subdirectory

My ZF2 project is in a subdirectory within my IIS 7.5 server, but the rewrite doesn't work.

The application only works through `www.domain.com/directory/subdirectory/public/index.php/controller/action`.

How can I configure rewrite in IIS

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to remove public/ index URL to access only www.domain.com/directory/subdirectory/controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the build rewrite engine in IIS. Put this file into `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsDirectory"
                             pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More information:

- [Zend Framework 2 Installation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html)
- [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)